# EF Core many-to-many relationship returns null for collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I want to create a many-to-many relationship in EF Core using MySQL so that a user can have many roles and roles can be assigned to many users. I followed [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many) but when I run `Users.SingleOrDefault()`, the result's roles collection is null.

```cs
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class DatabaseService : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        private static string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=user;Pwd=mypwd;";

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
                .WithMany(u => u.Users)
                .UsingEntity("UsersRoles");
        }
    }
```

Saving and querying data to/from the database

```cs
Collection<Role> roles = new()
{
    new Role
    {
        Name = "Customer"
    },
    new Role
    {
        Name = "Administrator"
    }
};

User newUser = new()
{
    Email = register.Email,
    Password = hashedPassword,
    FirstName = register.FirstName,
    LastName = register.LastName,
    Roles = roles
};

database.Users.Add(newUser);
database.SaveChanges();

User? user = database.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Email == login.Email && user.Password == HashPassword(login.Password));

Console.WriteLine(user.Roles); //null
```

Even though the DB's join table contains the data.

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). Use Eager loading with Include.

Comment: You have a Circular Dependency issue. Remove  public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } from Role class to fix it. See https://dev.to/sardarmudassaralikhan/what-is-circular-dependency-in-microsoft-aspnet-core-web-api-19hf  for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Alexander Pretrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045688/alexander-petrov)'s comment to my original post is the solution.

> [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). Use Eager loading with Include.

Comment: They did not post an answer, so i thought i would point to their comment to facilitate finding the answer

Comment: Comments can be deleted at any time for any reason. This answer needs to stand on its own—maybe you should copy the comment into your answer as a blockquote? (Though the comment you refer to is pretty close to being [link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/248627)...)

Comment: Alright, i edited my answer to include a quote.

Answer (score 0):

In the Role entity, try to make Users as virtual, I hope this will help you

```
`public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Similarly in the User entity:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

---

I am sorry, but I cannot comment that is why I posted an answer:

Comment: It didn't work, user.Roles is still null

Comment: Possibly there will be no role associated to this current user, otherwise it should get roles

Comment: It did not work because of a Circular Dependency. You can only have ONE virtual collection amongst 2 related tables and not in both. See https://dev.to/sardarmudassaralikhan/what-is-circular-dependency-in-microsoft-aspnet-core-web-api-19hf

Answer (score 0):

Please read on [Circular Dependency](https://dev.to/sardarmudassaralikhan/what-is-circular-dependency-in-microsoft-aspnet-core-web-api-19hf). To avoid circular dependencies in your ASP.NET Core Web API application, it is important to follow good architectural practices and design principles including:

- Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)
- Dependency Injection (DI)
- Modularization

To fix the issue, retain the dependent collection.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // Retain this
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And remove the principal collection.

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    //Add for foreign key
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // Remove this
    //public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the configuration, build the M:M relationship as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasOne(u => u.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Roles)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserId);
```